# export default HOC(SampleComponent) doesnt' work with functional component React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hoc

I am unable to use the react feature of HOC with functional component. 
In below code export default HOC({component: SampleComponent}) doesnt work

```
const SampleComponent: FC = () => {
  return (<div>Hello World</div>);
};

export default HOC({ component: SampleComponent });
```

And the HOC is simply

```
const HOC = ({ component: Component }) => {
  return (<Component/>);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HOC should be

```
const HOC = ({ component: Component }) => {
  return (props: {}) => (<Component/>);
}
```

Comment: Great ! Thanks this worked. Can you also tell why do we need to return a callback function  and not the component directly?

Comment: @Prernashah A HOC is a function that returns a component. The callback is a component that takes no props.

Comment: How can i use hooks in HOC now?

Comment: Can HOC not be considered as a functional component? It certainly returns React element ie Component here.

Comment: Also want to render this component conditionally , something like this-

<div>
    {!id  (
      <SomeOtherComponent
        prop1={'hello'}
        prop2={'world'}
      />
    ) : (
       <Component />
    )}
  </div>

Here id is coming as a response from graphql query hook, which again i am unable to use in HOC function.

Comment: A component is not an element. A component returns an element. And a HOC returns a component. An HOC is technically not a component because it does not return an element.

Comment: So can we not use hooks in HOC function?

Comment: Or can we not make HOC return a react element wrapping our component?Something like this-

<div>
   <Component />
</div>

Comment: I would suggest: mark the above answer as correct, and then post a new question with all the things you would like to know. It is easier for you to format your code examples that way, and other people can answer as well.